# Netbeans `The conditional statement is redundant`

Tags: java, netbeans, conditional-statements

Netbeans gives me `The conditional statement is redundant` warning for this:

```
return (this.getId(person) == null) ? false : true;
```

And if I comply with that, it changes to this:

```
return (this.getId(person) != null);
```

Are these two equal? How is the second one conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unwrap the first form to something like this:

```
boolean cnd = (this.getId(person) == null);
if (cnd)
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

This clearly shows that switching on a boolean value just to return the same boolean value is redundant.

The second statement is not conditional but it provides the same result with fewer hops.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say `getId` returns something that is not null. Is `== null` playing a conditional role here?

Comment: What I think NetBeans means by 'conditional' is the ternary operator  `cond ? val1 : val2` - it's usage is redundant here.

Comment: Forget about Netbeans. For an expression to be cast to a `boolean` there should be some kind of comparison. I'm asking whether in the 2nd one `this.getId(person) != null` is doing the comparison or not.

Comment: Obviusly it does - `!=` is the operator of non-equality, hence doing the comparison.

Answer (score 5):

Yes , They both  are  conceptually same.

The second one is not conditional. Its an expression resolves into `boolean`,  So simply you can result of that expression.

Why it is redundant in first case is , It's just like writing

```
   if(true){
      return true;
    }else{
     return false;
   }
```

Look at your condition

```
 this.getId(person) != null;
```

your `this.getId(person)`  may be `null`  or may not. So that expression resolves as `true` or `false` . That's it. Right ? So your IDE is telling that use that expression result.

Comment: You said it's not conditional. So `this.getId(person) != null;` is conditional anyway. Right?

Comment: No, it's not conditional, it returns `boolean`. Do not confuse.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `this.getId(person) == null` will return you `true` or `false`. Again adding a ternary operator is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a boolean value and

```
return (this.getId(person) != null);
```

is a boolean conditional statement that will evaluate to true or false. This is why the compiler is telling you that the conditional statement is redundant. It will still compile the other way but its more typing and it's not as clean.